# How to get standard exception output text

Tags: .net, error-handling, exception

Having caught an exception, how can I programatically obtain **string with standard exception text containing crash parameters P1-P10 etc.** (see bottom half of sample screenshot)

[image]

Currently I can obtain only string with stack trace.

Let's say I want to create error handling dialog mimicking standard JIT dialog keeping most of its current features, but localize and extend it.

Comment: what code do you have? if you don't have a try catch or rethrowing and nothing is catching it up the stack, then you will get the JIT dialog you are explaining. why not catch the exception and log it? the JIT dialog also gives you the stacktrace and everything you need (along with it being logged in the eventlog). you cant however redesign or extend the JIT dialog...

Comment: @Ahmedilyas - please check edited answer. I understand that existing dialog cannot be modified. I just wondered if string from textbox can be obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can get that whole string, so you'll have to assemble it yourself. The Exception Text part is `Exception.ToString()`, and you can get the loaded assemblies from `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`.